# Display the descriptive status of options

Tags: django

I define a article_table model data in modles.py, especially set a `options` attribute for `status`

```
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,  'normal'),
        (-1, 'deleted'),
    )
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000) # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I check the responded html, it display status with `0` from database rather than its description 'normal'

[image]

The status did not show `normal` as I intended.

The template of `article_list.html`

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Latest Updated</th>
    </tr>
    {% for article in articles %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ article.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.author }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.date_updated }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: Docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices), then you can use [`get_<fieldname>_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) in the template, like this:

```
{{ article.get_status_display }}
```